# How can I calculate a rotation matrix around an arbitrary axis?

Tags: matrices, vectors, rotations

Suppose I have a center at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, a vector $V$ goes from $(x_b, y_b, z_b)$ to $(x_e, y_e, z_e)$, and the translation vector is $(x_t, y_t, z_t)$.

I want to find the rotation matrix to rotate $30$ degrees around the vector $V$.

How can I calculate it?

Please give me a reference for further study.

Comment: Why do you have both, center and translation? What is the difference in your case? Based on your question, you just need an axis (which is already given by the two points). Can you clarify the setting a bit?

Comment: A rotation matrix will give you a rotation around an axis that passes through the origin of coordinates, $(0,0,0).$ You are talking about $(x_b, y_b, z_b)$ and $(x_e, y_e, z_e)$ -- do you want your axis of rotation to pass through both of those points? It might not pass through the origin then.